# Category errors and positive properties

Tags: fallacies, properties

A category error is what you get when you assert of an object x a property p which makes no sense when applied to x. Examples:

- The number two is red.
- The number two was created at time t.
- The dog is even (as in an even number).
- The idea seemed nervous.

There are two common ways to deal with category errors: You can say that a category error is false or you can say that it is meaningless. If you say that such a proposition is false, then you have to deal with the negation of the proposition. For example, if

A. The number two is red.

is to be counted as false, then in classical logic, it must be the case that

B. The number two is not red.

is true. But it is typically allowed that the negation of a property is itself a property, so non-red is a property. Now,

C. The number two is non-red.

is a category error, and if we are saying that all category errors are false, then C is false. But C is the same as B, which is true.

One way to deal with this would be to distinguish between positive and negative properties. So "red" would be a positive property and "non-red" would be negative. There are then several moves we could make in order to avoid the problem of B being true and C being false. However, can a distinction like this be maintained? What about even/odd? If we say that

D. The dog is even.

is false, then

E. The dog is not even.

Must be true. But E is equivalent to

F. The dog is odd.

which, by our rule of resolving category errors, is false.

My question: has anyone tried to deal with this issue by developing a theory of positive and negative properties that can successfully categorize every property as either positive or negative? Or is there some other way to deal with the contradiction issue?

Comment: The standard approach to categorized objects/properties is [many-sorted logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-many-sorted/) where category error expressions are ungrammatical and there is no negation problem. Positive/negative properties are discussed, but not for this purpose. [Gödel axiomatized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_ontological_proof#Outline) them for the ontological argument, for broader metaphysical uses see e.g. [Baron et al.](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/philosophy/article/what-is-a-negative-property/04889F08C85F2C9B587CE7CAB403E6E5)

Comment: As an aside, omega is sometimes taken to be both odd and even, so the odd/not-even equivalence falls apart.

Comment: Sometimes Philosophy is tired some. I mean, tiresome. Too bad there is no engine to make the tires go.

Comment: @KristianBerry, do you have any evidence besides the link you gave in your answer? That question wasn't using the usual definitions of odd and even. What exactly is the result of of dividing omega by two and how can it both have and not have a remainder?

Comment: @DavidGudeman usual definitions can routinely be extended in non-contradictory ways in math, e.g. if the domain of discourse is the reals, “if it’s nonnegative it has a square root, if it doesn’t have a square root it’s negative”. Then we adjoin *i* to the reals and this no longer holds.

Comment: @JKusin, yes, I'm familiar with basic mathematics. I still doubt that there is any standard definition of odd and even whereby omega is both odd and even.

Comment: You are correct. On the standard definition of [ordinal parity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_ordinals), ω is just even. However, if we extend the standard definition for integers, 2n for even, 2m+1 for odd, to other rings then there will be plenty of elements that are both even and odd. For example, every rational number is both even and odd. There is no way to maintain ¬ X = Y generally when X and Y are extended beyond their original category.

Comment: @Conifold, thanks for extending the nitpickery over my example, which was perfectly fine as it was.

Comment: Was it? You worried that there is a problem with assigning truth values because negative properties can be equivalent to positive properties. Arguably, properties can be set up so that there is no such equivalence intensionally, at most, they will be coextensional within native categories. Being outside, even-and-odd dogs need not interfere with truth assignments. This is actually good news for your proposal.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why the dog example isn't an actual counterexample is because the infinite ordinal omega, among other ordinals, is [both odd and even in some sense per this MathOverflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/a/86661/147890):

> First I'll remark that for the first question, note that the or cannot be exclusive since ω is both even and odd.

And though there is some sense to [distinguishing odd and even ordinals (or those that are only even from those both even and odd, perhaps)](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Egoldberg/Slides/EvenOrdinalsAndTheKunenInconsistency.pdf), this is not enough to make "even" = "not odd," neither *vice versa*, but if the dog is not odd, this doesn't mean it's even.

---

[More broadly-speaking, there are a variety of theories about what category mistakes are](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/category-mistakes/#AccoInfeCateMist), with some semantic approaches including [contentlessness and lack of truth-aptitude](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/category-mistakes/#SemaAppr). Perhaps, "The dog is even," has meaning, even content, but is not truth-apt?

**Corollary:** although I think the positive-/negative-properties distinction would be at least helpful, here, we might try a workaround, to some extent, based on [the sparse-/abundant-properties distinction](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/properties/#SparAbunConc) first or instead. Problems with negative properties are (presumably) akin to those with negative facts (variously discussed throughout the SEP, albeit, and strangely enough, very briefly in the article on facts in general!). So we might take "odd" and "even" for positive properties, deny the abundance-of-properties thesis, hold fast to, "The dog is neither even nor odd," and avoid any dire ontological commitments thereby the by. (If we do accept negative properties, we can still have "neither even nor odd" for a negative *disjunctive* property to boot; this would open the door to a more complex taxonomy of options like, "There are only positive non-disjunctive properties," "There are positive properties, including some disjunctive ones," "There are both positive and negative properties but no disjunctive ones," etc.)

Comment: That MathOverflow question made up new definitions of "even" and "odd". I was using the normal definitions.

Comment: @DavidGudeman if you were using those definitions, then you wouldn't conclude that a dog is even if not odd, since you would think that dividing the dog into two parts wouldn't leave a remainder anymore than dividing a dog into three parts, would it?

Comment: I don't think you got the point of the question.

Comment: @DavidGudeman isn't the question partly based on an incorrect assumption, that "even" = "not odd"? Maybe you could find a more stable example of the problem, though.

Comment: I should add that I think your suggestion about positive properties is very much worth considering in this connection; I'm not arguing against that suggestion, and I like that you tried to find a counterexample to your own proposal, so I'm defending your initial proposal against the counter.

Comment: Sure, I wasn't taking it personally, but the whole point of the example was that it didn't make sense and then you claimed it must mean something else because it didn't make sense.